# Spring Data REST - "Can only translate enum with property information!" error when PATCH an entity containing a set of enum

Tags: java, spring-boot, enums, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I setup the **enum traslation** in my Spring Data REST project (Spring Boot v.1.5.6):

```
spring.data.rest.enable-enum-translation=true
```

One of the entity has an enum set property. When I try to PATCH this entity to increase a number of enum in the set - I've got an error(!):

> Could not read payload!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can only translate enum with property information!

If I update the enum set with the same number of enum (or less) then the entity is updated correctly.

PUT updates an enum set correctly in anyway.

If I turn off the the enum traslation then PATCH works as expected.

Does anybody know how to workaround this issue? Is this a bug?

**Code**

```java
@Entity
public class User {

    private String name;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @CollectionTable(name = "roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    @ElementCollection
    private Set<Role> roles;

    // other stuff 
}

public enum Role {
    ADMIN, USER, POWER_USER
}
```

**resources/rest-messages.properties**

```
# Enums
io.github.cepr0.enumtranslatingissue.Role.ADMIN=Admin
io.github.cepr0.enumtranslatingissue.Role.USER=User
io.github.cepr0.enumtranslatingissue.Role.POWER_USER=Power user
```

**Error demo**

```json
GET http://localhost:8080/api/users/1
{
    "name": "user1",
    "roles": [
        "Admin",
        "User"
    ],
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/users/1"
        },
        "user": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/users/1"
        }
    }
}

PATCH http://localhost:8080/api/users/1
{
  "roles": [
          "Admin",
          "User",
          "Power user"
      ]
}

{
    "cause": {
        "cause": null,
        "message": "Can only translate enum with property information!"
    },
    "message": "Could not read payload!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can only translate enum with property information!"
}
```

[Demo project](https://github.com/Cepr0/enum-translating-issue)

Comment: The value "Power user" in your json array has a space character. You can't have spaces in enums.

Comment: @patelb Yes you are right, these are not enums - it's their 'translation'. It is the SDR feature (see my updated question)...